# Allow key-rebinding in a type, with React Component

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript

I want to be able to have a component in React, that takes an input that has to have 2 mandatory keys, `id` and `name`. It's absolutely needed so that the utility function can work properly, since it will be using those fields to access the data of interest.

That, I successfully did !

Now, I want to have an argument `keysMapping` that allows for my user to be able to remap those needed keys ! So, for instance, if my user has both `id` and `displayName` instead, he'd be able to remap the used key as `id` and `displayName`. Basically, `id` and `name` are used by default.

My current entire system in a MCVE looks like this

```js
// Defining a set of mandatory keys, with their values;
type MandatoryKeys = {
    id: string | number;
    name: string;
};

type KeysMapping<T> = Record<keyof MandatoryKeys, keyof T>;

const useKey = <T extends MandatoryKeys>(
    item: T,
    key: keyof MandatoryKeys,
    keysMapping?: KeysMapping<T>,
) => {
    const keyToUse = keysMapping ? keysMapping[key] : key;
    return item[keyToUse];
}

type MyComponentProps<T> = {
    items: T[],
    keysMapping?: KeysMapping<T>,
}
const MyComponent = <T extends MandatoryKeys,>(props: MyComponentProps<T>) => {
    const { items, keysMapping } = props;

    items.map( (item) => {
        const a = useKey(item, "id", keysMapping);
        const b = useKey(item, "name", keysMapping);
    })

    return <div/>;
}
```

And for my current use-cases. I feel like I've tried to do hundreds of different combinations, but this is the point where I think I am the closest to succeeding. Though I don't know what to do with this `extends MandatoryKeys`...

```js
const ParentExample = () => {
    type CT = { id: string, name: string, field: string }
    const data: CT[] = [{ id: "a", name: "b", field: "C" }]
    const mapping: KeysMapping<CT> = { "id": "field", "name": "name" }
    const _1 = <MyComponent items={data} keysMapping={mapping}/>;
    // No error everything is fine !
    const _3 = <MyComponent items={data}/>
    // No error, everything is fine !
    
    
    type CT2 = { name: string, field: string }
    const data2: CT2[] = [{ name: "b", field: "C" }]
    const mapping2: KeysMapping<CT2> = { "id": "field", "name": "name" }
    const _2 = <MyComponent items={data2} keysMapping={mapping2}/>
    // This fails, but I want it to SUCCESS because even though `id` is missing
    // The mapping is here, and should be able to say... It's enough ! I've made the proper checks now I'm here.

    // items :      Property 'id' is missing in type 'CT2' but required in type 'MandatoryKeys'.
    // keysMapping: Type 'KeysMapping<CT2>' is not assignable to type 'KeysMapping<MandatoryKeys>'.
    //              Property 'field' is missing in type 'MandatoryKeys' but required in type 'CT2'.


    const _2 = <MyComponent items/>
    // This fails, but it's normal. I don't have the required keys, AND no mapping is given to balance that.

    return <Fragment />
}
```

I am also open to new strategies about how to tackle my problem. I felt like the `keysMapping` was a beautiful way of handling that bit of code, but maybe I'm entirely going the wrong way...